# how can i get a honeyd rpm?

Tags: rpm

I am running Centos 6, I am looking for a honeyd rpm that is safe to use. Where can I get it? I'd rather not compile from source.

I've tried looking in the CentOS epel repository, but it is not there. I found it in homebrew, but that seems to be mostly for MacOs users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the latest source RPM from http://pkgs.repoforge.org/honeyd/. Then you can run `rpmbuild --rebuild my-honeyd-version.src.rpm` and that will recompile and rebuild the honeyd rpm for your distribution. This is probably the best way to do it, because you can verify the integrity of the rpm yourself, instead of grabbing a random one of pbone or other rpm aggregators.

Comment: Use `mock` to build the source RPM instead. It will automatically resolve any build dependencies and clean up after itself, so you don't have to worry about it.